# Testing the database changes against the active application in a Blue/Green deployment setup

Tags: asp.net-web-api, deployment, continuous-integration, octopus-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I'm looking at implementing a blue/green deployment strategy. It will be for a database driven web application. We are using Teamcity and Octopus deploy currently.

To my knowledge, to achieve this strategy, the changes to the database need to be such that both versions of applications will continue to work, so in the case the of a rollback, the database changes don't need to be reverted.

I have read Octopus suggested implementation of this [here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Blue-green+deployments).

My *question*:

- Does anyone test the current active application in prod against the database changes prior to promoting to prod? E.g. In Test or UAT?
- If so, how do you fit this requirement with the deployment strategy, especially when configuring it with Octopus?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone test the current active application in prod against database changes prior to promoting to prod.

Octopus lets you easily deploy the current live version to your pre-production environment, so you can test it against the upgraded database prior to deploying the upgraded database to your live server.

So if you have version `1` of your application live with database version `a`, and have version `b` of your database coming through, followed by version `2` of your application, you can test this in pre-production...

```
1 a - Same as live
1 b - First phase of testing (followed by release of `b`)
2 b - Second phase of testing (followed by release of `2`)
```